# gcloud compute ssh refuses connection (return code 255)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys, gcloud

I cannot get ssh access into the vm instance created by Google Cloud command line tool (gcloud).

Symptom:

```
sudo gcloud compute ssh myuser@ubuntu
ssh: connect to host 104.155.16.104 port 22: Connection refused
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

What I did:

1: Verify that firewall is open on port 22

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

returned

```
NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES    RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS
allow-rstudio           default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:8787                                allow-rstudio
default-allow-http      default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:80                                  http-server
default-allow-https     default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:443                                 
https-server
default-allow-icmp      default  0.0.0.0/0     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  10.128.0.0/9  tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:22
```

2: Renew public key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -C myuser
```

3: Update metadata with new public key

```
sudo gcloud compute ssh myuser@ubuntu
Updating project ssh metadata...
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                                                                                                                     
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
```

Then, still the same error message:

```
ssh: connect to host 35.187.38.82 port 22: Connection refused
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I should add that I could access ssh until today, and of course, I did authentication before with
    gcloud auth login

SSH from the Google Cloud web interface works! What is different there?
Would be grateful for any help!!

Comment: for people who downgraded: it would be great to provide an intelligent hint why the specific error message "connection refused" shows even though the port 22 is open!

Comment: @Kenster thank you for the interesting link. unfortunately i already had gone through all the advice there (using -vvv, replacing the ssh keys). Besides, there is no answer for the specific error message "connection confused" except the obvious firewall port being closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a long search, I finally found the underlying reason for this tricky problem. I hope that this will help some people in desperation...

The reason you may get your ssh connection refused is that accidentally, the internal routing for external ip requests was deleted. You can check this by:

```
gcloud compute routes list
```

If this does not return a list including the following entry:

```
default-internet       default     0.0.0.0/0       default-internet-gateway 1000
```

Then you must re-create this entry by:

```
gcloud compute routes create default-internet \
--destination-range 0.0.0.0/0 \
--next-hop-gateway default-internet-gateway
```

Comment: Just running this fixed it for me, although I had the entry pre-existing.

Comment: I have this entry and still can't ssh

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I had the entry in the list before running the command

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after I made an upgrade of the GCP instance (just added more processor and memory).

My Circle CI deploy started throwing:

```
Authentication failed.

Exited with code 255
```

After a couple of hours trying to figure out what messed up, I found that the contents of the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** was emptied with no reason at all.
What fixed my problem is to recreate this file and restart the ssh service.

**Note**: PasswordAuthentication should be set to:

```
   PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: How did you do this if you can't connect to the system? I'm having this issue.. I upgraded instance and no longer can get in.

Answer (score 1):

For the poor, suffering souls who stumble upon this.

The following works for me with consistency:

> On your machine in gcloud CLI run `gcloud init` and go through the
> prompts.

The end. I hope this helps you my dear, internet fellow-sufferer.

Comment: and to create a brand new 'profile'

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was that I was running a `nohup` process on the instance, all of a sudden the process stopped working.

After spending a lot of time investigating, I found that the instance itself hung-up. We miss small things like that, getting caught debugging the bigger problem

Check if you're able to `ping` your instance. If not, restart it and `ssh`, it will work fine. This is one of the solutions.